# One or both of Username and Password are invalid

Tags: docusignapi

I have developed an integration using docusign SOAP API.  We had the integration certified.  It works great using the demo API URLs and my dev account.  When I update the API URLs to production and use my live production account I get the return status of "One or both of Username and Password are invalid" when I call `CreateEnvelope()`.  I have verified the user name and password are correct.  I use them to log into the production account.  I am setting the username in the code like [APIKEY]APIUSERNAME.

Does a DocuSign account need to be authorized to use an integration?  How do I know my integrators key was moved over to production after certification?  Any ideas when this works in dev but not in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to follow up and post the answer to this issue.  After working with Partner support I was able to get things working.

The issue was related to using the wrong base url when I created my api proxy.  I was just passing in the docusign production url, when I actually needed to get this in the configuration for each user that uses the integration.  When I get the base url in the config part of the app it return the actual server which the users account resided on (which includes the na1 or na2 etc server name in the url).  After adding this to the config and using this new base url in my calls the app works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I believe DocuSign production accounts need to be authorized to use the API.  If you are positive that you are passing the correct username and password in your code then it's quite possible that this is an account issue.

For resolution I would suggest the following.  For questions regarding your integration key and if it was indeed promoted to production following your successful certification you should contact

```
apicertifications@docusign.com
```

And if you have an account manager you might want to try reaching out to them as well, which might get your questions answered sooner.